# Running the rebuild_index command more than once looks like it tokenizes values again

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I notice strange behavior when running the the `rebuild_index` command multiple times from one Python shell session.

In this example I ran `rebuild_index` from the Bash shell and then entered the Python shell to check the facet values. They are capitalized. Then I ran the `rebuild_index` command from the Python shell and the facet values were in lowercase.

```
$ bin/manage rebuild_index
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: Non-OK status code returned (404) containing u'IndexMissingException[[my_index] missing]'.
All documents removed.
Indexing 40 components.


In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

In [2]: SearchQuerySet().models(Component).facet('primary_language').facet_counts()
Out[2]:
{'dates': {},
 'fields': {'primary_language': [(u'Java', 24),
   (u'Scala', 5),
   (u'C', 3),
   (u'Python', 2),
   (u'C++', 2),
   (u'PHP', 1),
   (u'Javascript', 1),
   (u'Ada', 1),
   (u'.Net', 1)]},
 'queries': {}}

In [3]: from django.core import management

In [4]: management.call_command('rebuild_index', interactive=False, verbosity=0)
Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: Non-OK status code returned (404) containing u'IndexMissingException[[my_index] missing]'.

In [5]: SearchQuerySet().models(Component).facet('primary_language').facet_counts()
Out[5]:
{'dates': {},
 'fields': {'primary_language': [(u'java', 24),
   (u'scala', 5),
   (u'c', 5),
   (u'python', 2),
   (u'php', 1),
   (u'net', 1),
   (u'javascript', 1),
   (u'ada', 1)]},
 'queries': {}}
```

The next weird thing is that if I run the `rebuild_index` command from the Python shell and try to order by the `name` field, I get an ElasticSearch error.

```
$ bin/manage rebuild_index
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index in connection 'default'.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: Non-OK status code returned (404) containing u'IndexMissingException[[my_index] missing]'.
All documents removed.
Indexing 40 components.


In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet

In [2]: SearchQuerySet().order_by('name')
Out[2]: [<SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'2')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'1')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'5')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'4')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'3')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'6')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'7')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'8')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'9')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'11')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'14')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'13')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'15')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'19')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'20')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'21')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'22')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'23')>, <SearchResult: my_app.component (pk=u'24')>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']

In [3]: from django.core import management

In [4]: management.call_command('rebuild_index', interactive=False, verbosity=0)
Failed to clear Elasticsearch index: Non-OK status code returned (404) containing u'IndexMissingException[[my_index] missing]'.

In [5]: SearchQuerySet().order_by('name')
Failed to query Elasticsearch using '*:*': Non-OK status code returned (500) containing u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], total failure; shardFailures {[SkgxFvdjRgyoiHv2qSpfbQ][my_index][4]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[my_index][4]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(QueryWrapperFilter(django_ct:my_app.component)))))->cache(_type:modelresult)],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:"name": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@3cb9b947>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can\'t sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }{[SkgxFvdjRgyoiHv2qSpfbQ][my_index][0]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[my_index][0]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(QueryWrapperFilter(django_ct:my_app.component)))))->cache(_type:modelresult)],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:"name": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@249cf580>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can\'t sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }{[SkgxFvdjRgyoiHv2qSpfbQ][my_index][3]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[my_index][3]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(QueryWrapperFilter(django_ct:my_app.component)))))->cache(_type:modelresult)],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:"name": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@4ff80724>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can\'t sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }{[SkgxFvdjRgyoiHv2qSpfbQ][my_index][2]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[my_index][2]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(QueryWrapperFilter(django_ct:my_app.component)))))->cache(_type:modelresult)],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:"name": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@99b8b51>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can\'t sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }{[SkgxFvdjRgyoiHv2qSpfbQ][my_index][1]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[my_index][1]: query[filtered(ConstantScore(NotDeleted(cache(QueryWrapperFilter(django_ct:my_app.component)))))->cache(_type:modelresult)],from[0],size[20],sort[<custom:"name": org.elasticsearch.index.field.data.strings.StringFieldDataType$1@42d777c4>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: IOException[Can\'t sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field]; }]'.
Out[5]: []
```

After this I exited the Python shell. I started another Python shell. I ran the following lines and the result was correct.

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('rebuild_index', interactive=False, verbosity=0)
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
SearchQuerySet().order_by('name')
```

This led me to the conclusion that `rebuild_index` can be run successfully only once during the life of a Python interpreter. It looks like running it a second time in a Python interpreter makes Haystack tokenize the values again. This explains why the facet values were returned in lowercase. It also explains the error message I got when trying to sort the results: "Can't sort on string types with more than one value per doc, or more than one token per field". It must be breaking the `name` values by the space character into multiple values.

Now here's the question, why does it matter to Haystack if I run `rebuild_index` more than once in a Python interpreter? I don't understand this because `rebuild_index` also runs `clear_index` as the first operation. Shouldn't clearing the index be a sufficient way to ensure that rebuilding the index again gets you the same thing? Apparently this is not true. I have no idea why.

The real dilemma here is how on earth am I supposed to write proper unit tests (where `rebuild_index` is run in `setUp()`) if I can't
1) retrieve facet values in their original formatting?
2) I can't order by a field that has values with spaces?

Any explanations, suggestions, or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because instance variables in the backend need to be reset before running `rebuild_index` a second time.

```
from django.core import management
from haystack import connections
backend = connections['default'].get_backend()
backend.setup_complete = False
backend.existing_mapping = None
management.call_command('rebuild_index', interactive=False, verbosity=0)
```